# terminate python while loop in php

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

Just having a problem on my Raspberry Pi project

I have a web server running on a Raspberry Pi and I write a web interface with some buttons to control the Pi. The Pi will run the python script in a "while True" loop initially. It stands for auto mode.

Here is the question. When I click the button on the webpage, I want to switch to manual mode. That means I want to terminate the "while True" loop and run some other python scripts. How can I achieve it in my webpage? Also considering that I may want to switch back to auto mode.

```
window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
    $('#power-switch').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
        if(data.value == true){
            var $el = $(data.el)
            , value = data.value;
            //console.log('on',e, $el, value);//for debug

            /*
            add your function here
            */
            js_pw_ON();


            $('#auto-switch').bootstrapSwitch('setActive', true);
            $('#lgt1').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#lgt2').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#lgt3').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#lgt4').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#lgt5').prop('disabled', false);
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to use some sort of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Can you explain it in details? Actually I don't need to pass information between python and the webpage. All I need is to run different scripts on different buttons.

Comment: You still need some sort of IPC to tell the process to stop. Is this on Linux? You could send it a [signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve your goal is to use file called lets say "manual_mode" with 0 or 1 inside. Ofcourse both php and python have to have permissions to file.

Php deals pretty well with files. Well if you want manual mode on:

```
file_put_contents('manual_mode','1');
```

Off:

```
file_put_contents('manual_mode','0');
```

Python deals pretty well with files aswell:

```
while 1:
    f = open('manual_mode','r')
    val = f.read()
    f.close()
    if val == '1':
        break
```

**EDIT:** In case you use jquery, you should first make switch.php file:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['sw']) && $_GET['sw'] == 1)
{
  file_put_contents('manual_mode','1');
} else
{
  file_put_contents('manual_mode','0');
}
```

When you call this like *switch.php?sw=1* manual_mode will be set to 1 (to 0 otherwise). What you gonna do next is to perform call to php script from your jquery code:

```
$.get("switch.php?sw=1");
```

I think that is all you need.

Btw. According to comments, IPC is platform dependent while files are not, so choice is obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I use a Bootstrap switch to switch between auto and manual mode. How can I put the "file_put_contents" on this switch buttons? I added the code of the switch in the original question